# MongoDB: How to query or a container document that contains only embedded documents with a certain attribute value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

Ok, let me try to explain what I am  trying to achieve...

Let's say that I have a collection HOUSE that embeds ROOMS. Each house has many rooms.
Let's say that each room has a color attribute (blue, red, green, etc.)

Now if I want to retrieve all the houses that have a room of the color blue, I can go ahead and simply do for instance

```
House.where(:'rooms.color' => :blue)
```

However what I really want is to query all the houses that ONLY have blue rooms. And that I have no idea how to do... I could create a new attribute at the HOUSE level to "mark" if the rooms are all of the same given colors... but I would rather avoid that if I could since my current data set would need to be upgraded to reflect that.

Thanks,

Alex

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
House.only(:'rooms.color' => :blue)
```

Comment: This is not the function of "only" with mongoid, it will limit the fields to display for a given document, preventing from loading all the data if it's not necessary. Thanks for trying though :)

Comment: Ah, sorry I guess I didn't understand the question exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about it with a step back... I was actually going at this the wrong way, sometime you have to negate :)

Basically having a house that only has Blue rooms, means that this house has no rooms of other colors...

So imagining that I have a finite set of possible colors like: :red :green :blue then in order to find the house that have only blue rooms, I only need to find house that have no :red or :green rooms :)

```
House.where(:'rooms.color'.nin => [:red, :green])
```

should do the trick :)

Alex

Answer (score 0):

@Alex You are better judge of your dataset, but theoretically following should also do the trick.

```
house_ids = House.where("rooms.color" => :blue).only(:_id).map(&:_id)
unwanted_house_ids = House.where("rooms.color".to_sym.ne => :blue).only(:_id).map(&:_id)
houses_with_only_blue_rooms = House.all.for_ids(house_ids - unwanted_house_ids)
```